# How to georeference images with GCP's in straight line?

Tags: georeferencing, qgis-2, ground-control, thin-plate-splines

I would like to use the Thin Plate Spline tranformation type in the QGIS georeferencer plugin. The image I'm trying to georeference is a sequence of aerial images which have been merged manually. I have the coordinates (position of the UAV at the time of taking a picture) of all the centers of the images which form the resulting flight line image. A screenshot to illustrate what I'm trying to do: [image: screenshot]

The result is very disappointing though, it's all stretched and wonky (see 2nd picture). I tried polynomial 2 and 3 and both of them were trash as well. Helmert gives a decent result but it's not what I need, I need to nullify the errors on the GCP's, therefore I'd like to use a TPS. Any clue on what I could do to fix it?

[image: TPS result]